# Drupal 7 Can't add date sort criteria

Tags: views

I have a view that display a list of nodes of a content type that has a date field.
I'm trying to add a sort criteria based on this data field, I can select it but hust after that I get returned to the main views screen, without the data sort.

I know that data fields are sortable so where can I have more informations about "why" this field is not added to sort criteria?

Answer (score 1):

It will avialable in Format -> Settings -> Check 'Stortable' Check box

[image]

Comment: My view is not a table format but an unformatted list of rendered items

Comment: Then where user will click the sort if it is not table?

Comment: I never told that users can sort items, I want a default sort not exposed.

Comment: What about Sort Criteria? Cant you find that?

Comment: OMG I know where sort criteria is but when I add the date field... read first post!

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem: drupal views module can't handle fields with a machine name longer or equal to 24 chars, so I used this module https://www.drupal.org/project/field_rename to change the custom date field name and now everything is ok!